# Magento 2.4.5 - How to disable Payment Transaction Failed Reminder Emails?

Tags: magento2.4.5

In Magento 2.4.5, under Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Payment Failed Emails, there is no option to disable this email altogether.

I would like to disable Magento from sending out this email when a payment fails.
Does anyone know how to do this, or why it isn't an option in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disable it from the code level. To do this, you can create a custom module or edit the core files directly.

To disable payment transaction failed reminder emails in the code level, follow these steps:

1. Create a custom module or locate an existing one.
2. Create a file at the path app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/events.xml.
3. Add the following code to the file:

   ```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="email_payment_failed">
            <observer name="[module]_payment_failed_observer" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\PaymentFailedObserver" />
        </event>
    </config>
   ```
4. Create the file at the path app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Observer/PaymentFailedObserver.php.
5. Add the following code to the file:

   ```
    <?php
    namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

    class PaymentFailedObserver implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $transport = $observer->getTransport();
            $transport['enabled'] = false;
            $observer->setTransport($transport);
        }
    }
   ```

6.Run the following command from your Magento root directory to enable the module:

```
php bin/magento module:enable [Vendor]_[Module]
```

7. Run the following command from your Magento root directory to update the database schema:

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   After completing these steps, Magento will no longer send payment transaction failed reminder emails.

Comment: I tried this code but still got an email.  I did a full redeploy after enabling it.  I had to also add a registration.php and module.xml for it to allow me to install.  Vendor and module can be anything I assume?

Comment: Yes Vendor and module you can change name space as per your requirement. But this module should be work as far as I know.